# Connection "default" was not found with TypeORM

Tags: node.js, postgresql, typeorm, nestjs

I use TypeORM with NestJS and I am not able to save properly an entity.

The connection creation works, postgres is running on 5432 port. Credentials are OK too.

However when I need to save a resource with entity.save() I got :

```
Connection "default" was not found.


Error
    at new ConnectionNotFoundError (/.../ConnectionNotFoundError.ts:11:22)
```

I checked the source file of TypeORM ConnectionManager (https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/src/connection/ConnectionManager.ts) but it seems that the first time TypeORM creates connection it attributes "default" name if we don't provide one, which is the case for me.

I setup TypeORM with TypeOrmModule as

```
TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
      type: config.db.type,
      host: config.db.host,
      port: config.db.port,
      username: config.db.user,
      password: config.db.password,
      database: config.db.database,
      entities: [
        __dirname + '/../../dtos/entities/*.entity.js',
      ]
    })
```

Of course my constants are correct. Any ideas ?

Comment: I assume you must provide `entities` to the TypeORM configuration (e.g. `entities: 'src/*/**.entity.ts'`).

Comment: Yes I have referenced my entities this way : ```entities: [
        __dirname + '/../../dtos/entities/*.entity.js',
      ]```, I edit my post

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You are trying to create a repository or manager without the connection being established.

Try doing this `const shopkeeperRepository = getRepository(Shopkeeper);` inside a function. it will work

Answer (score 14):

the upvoted answer is not necessarily correct, if you not specify the connection name it will default to "default".

```
const manager = getConnectionManager().get('your_orm_name');
const repository = manager.getRepository<AModel>(Model);
```

Comment: I have tried that connectionManager but i am getting the same error.

Answer (score 7):

If anyone else has this problem in the future, check this out just in case:

I accidentally did "`user.save()`" instead of "`userRepo.save(user)`".

(And of course above initializing the connection like this:

```
const userRepo = getConnection(process.env.NODE_ENV).getRepository(User)
```

Answer (score 4):

We are using `lerna` and using code from library `A`  in package `B`.

**The problem was** that both TypeOrm versions in each package differ.

**Solution is** to make sure that you have exactly the same version installed in each package.

To be on the safe side, delete your `node_modules` directory and reinstall everything again with `yarn install` or `npm install`

Check your `yarn.lock` for multiple entries of `typeorm` and make sure there is only one.

Comment: If you got this error when using `npm link`, use `npm install $(npm pack <path_to_linked_lib> | tail -1)` instead. This ensures that only one matching typeorm version is installed in the target project (if the typeorm semver versions match).

Answer (score 3):

**If anyone using Express Router with `getRepository()`, check the code below**

```
const router = Router();

router.get("/", async function (req: Request, res: Response) {
  // here we will have logic to return all users
  const userRepository = getRepository(User);
  const users = await userRepository.find();
  res.json(users);
});

router.get("/:id", async function (req: Request, res: Response) {
  // here we will have logic to return user by id
  const userRepository = getRepository(User);
  const results = await userRepository.findOne(req.params.id);
  return res.send(results);
});
```

Just make sure to call `getRepository()` in every route just like Saras Arya said in the accepted answer.

Comment: Thanks, it works. But calling getRepository in each route is not a good way.

Answer (score 3):

I follow the below approach creating the `Database` class. If the connection doesn't exist then it creates the connection else return the existing connection.

```
import { Connection, ConnectionManager, ConnectionOptions, createConnection, getConnectionManager } from 'typeorm';

export class Database {
  private connectionManager: ConnectionManager;

  constructor() {
    this.connectionManager = getConnectionManager();
  }

  public async getConnection(name: string): Promise<Connection> {
    const CONNECTION_NAME: string = name;
    let connection: Connection;
    const hasConnection = this.connectionManager.has(CONNECTION_NAME);
    if (hasConnection) {
      connection = this.connectionManager.get(CONNECTION_NAME);
      if (!connection.isConnected) {
        connection = await connection.connect();
      }
    } else {

      const connectionOptions: ConnectionOptions = {
        name: 'default',
        type: 'mysql',
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 3306,
        username: 'root',
        password: 'password',
        database: 'DemoDb',
        synchronize: false,
        logging: true,
        entities: ['src/entities/**/*.js'],
        migrations: ['src/migration/**/*.js'],
        subscribers: ['src/subscriber/**/*.js'],
      };
      connection = await createConnection(connectionOptions);
    }
    return connection;
  }
}
```

If you are using webpack the make sure entities are imported specifically & returned in array.

```
    import {User} from 'src/entities/User.ts';
    import {Album} from 'src/entities/Album.ts';
    import {Photos} from 'src/entities/Photos.ts';
    const connectionOptions: ConnectionOptions = {
        name: 'default',
        type: 'mysql',
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 3306,
        username: 'root',
        password: 'password',
        database: 'DemoDb',
        synchronize: false,
        logging: true,
        entities: [User, Album, Photos],
        migrations: ['src/migration/**/*.js'],
        subscribers: ['src/subscriber/**/*.js'],
      };
```

Finally

```
  const connectionName = 'default';
  const database = new Database();
  const dbConn: Connection = await database.getConnection(connectionName);
  const MspRepository = dbConn.getRepository(Msp);
  await MspRepository.delete(mspId);
```

Answer (score 1):

For those of you looking for another answer, check this out.

In my case, the issue was because I was passing `name` in my db config.

```
export const dbConfig = {
    name: 'myDB',
    ...
}

await createConnection(dbConfig) // like this
```

As a result, the only connection server knows is `myDB` not `default`.

At the same time, in my service, repository was injected without `name` which will fallback to `default`. (Service will looking for `default` connection as a result)

```
@Service() // typedi
export class Service {
    constructor(
        // inject without name -> fallback to default
        @InjectRepository() private readonly repository
    ) {}
}
```

As a fix, I removed `name` property in my db config.

Or you can pass `myDB` as a parameter for `InjectRepository` like `@InjectRepository('myDB')`, either way works.

Answer (score 1):

In my own case, the actual problem was that my `index` file imports my `router` file which imports my controllers which then import my services (where the call to `getRepository` was made). So the imports were resolving (and thus the call to `getRepository`) before the connection was established.

I considered implementing [Sarya's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50542841/13839228) but it's going to leave my code more verbose.

What I did was create a function to connect to the DB in a `db/index.ts` file

```
import { createConnection } from "typeorm";

export const getDBConnection = async () => {
  const dbConnection = await createConnection();
  if (!dbConnection.isConnected) await dbConnection.connect();
  return dbConnection;
}
```

Then create an async function to bootstrap my app. I wait on `getDBConnection` to resolve before instantiating my app then I import my router file after. That way the import resolution only happens after the connection has been established.

`routers/index.ts`

```
import { Router } from 'express';

const router = Router();

/* ... route configurations ... */

export default router;
```

`app.ts`

```
const bootstrap = async () => {
  try {
    // wait on connection to be established
    await getDBConnection();
  } catch (error) {
    // log error then throw
    throw error;
  }

  // create app
  const app = express();

  // some middleware configuration...

  // now import and setup the router
  const { default: router } = await import("./routers");
  app.use("/api", router);

  // some more middleware configuration...

  const server = http.createServer(app);
  server.listen(3000, () => console.log('app running at port: 3000'));
};

bootstrap();
```

Answer (score 0):

Although Saras Arya has provided the correct answer, I have encountered the same error

> ConnectionNotFoundError: Connection "default" was not found.

due to the fact that my `typeORM` entity did have an `@Entity()` decorator as well as that it had extended `BaseEntity`.

The two can't live together.

Comment: Not if you're using active record pattern: https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/active-record-data-mapper.md

Comment: Ut works fine when I launch it with `ts-node` and starts to fail after transpilation. What do you mean `two can't live together`? Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

I got this error while using `getConnectionOptions` for different environments. Using one database for development and another for testing. This is how I fixed it:

```
const connectionOptions = await getConnectionOptions(process.env.NODE_ENV);
await createConnection({...connectionOptions, name:"default"});
```

I use`getConnectionOptions` to get the connection for the current environment, in order to do that successfully you have to change `ormconfig.json` to an array, with keys "name" containing the different environments you want, like so:

```
[
{
    "name" : "development",
    "type": "USER",
    "host": "localhost",
    "port": 5432,
    "username": "postgres",
    "password": "PASS",
    "database": "YOURDB"
},
{
    "name" : "test",
    "type": "USERTEST",
    "host": "localhost",
    "port": 5432,
    "username": "postgres",
    "password": "PASSTEST",
    "database": "YOURDBTEST"
}
]
```

Now `connectionOptions` will contain the connection parameters of the current environment, but loading it to `createConnection` threw the error you pointed. Changing `connectionOptions` name to "default" fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is super weird but someone might need this:

`Windows` related reason.

I had the same error caused by the current location set with the drive letter in the lower case (`d:/apps/app-name/etc`). 
The problem got fixed once I updated the directory change instruction to use capital `D` (`D:/apps/app-name/etc`).

Answer (score 0):

After verifying TypeOrm versions is same in both the packages i.e- external package and consumer repository as mentioned by @InsOp still issue persist then issue could be-

Basically when we create an external package - TypeORM tries to get the *"default"* connection option, but If not found then throws an error:

> ConnectionNotFoundError: Connection "default" was not found.

We can solve this issue by doing some kind of **sanity check** before establishing a connection - luckily we have `.has()` method on `getConnectionManager()`.

```js
import { Connection, getConnectionManager, getConnectionOptions, 
  createConnection, getConnection, QueryRunner } from 'typeorm';
    
    async init() {
    let connection: Connection;
    let queryRunner: QueryRunner;

     if (!getConnectionManager().has('default')) {
        const connectionOptions = await getConnectionOptions();
        connection = await createConnection(connectionOptions);
      } else {
        connection = getConnection();
      }

    queryRunner = connection.createQueryRunner(); 
 }
```

Above is a quick code-snippet which was the actual **root cause** for this issue but If you are interested to see complete working repositories (different examples) -

- External NPM Package :

  - Git Repo : [git-unit-of-work](https://github.com/tsabunkar/unit-of-work) (specific file- *src/providers/typeorm/typeorm-uow.ts*)
  - Published in NPM : [npm-unit-of-work](https://www.npmjs.com/package/unit-of-work)
- Consumer of above package : [nest-typeorm-postgre](https://github.com/tsabunkar/nest-typeorm-postgre) (specific files- *package.json, src/countries/countries.service.ts & countries.module.ts*)

Answer (score 0):

In my case was that I have an array of multiple connections, instead of just one. You have 2 alternatives.

- To have at least one `default` named connection, example:

```js
createConnections([
  {
    name: 'default',
    type: 'mysql',
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 3306,
    username: 'root',
    password: 'root',
    database: 'users',
    entities: [`${__dirname}/entity/*{.js,.ts}`],
    synchronize: true,
    logging: true
  }
]);
```

- To be specific when using the connection:

```js
import {getConnection} from "typeorm";

const db1Connection = getConnection("db1Connection");
// you can work with "db1" database now...
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem with the following code:

```
import { HttpException, Inject, NotFoundException } from "@nestjs/common";
import { Not } from "typeorm";
import { Transactional } from "typeorm-transactional-cls-hooked";
import { TENANT_CONNECTION } from "../tenant/tenant.module";
import {Feriados} from './feriados.entity';  

export class FeriadosService {
   repository: any;

constructor(
@Inject(TENANT_CONNECTION) private connection)
{
  this.repository = connection.getRepository(Feriados)
}

@Transactional()
async agregar(tablaNueva: Feriados): Promise<Number> {
  const tablaAGuardar = await this.repository.create(tablaNueva)
  return await this.guardar(tablaAGuardar)
}

@Transactional()
async actualizar(tablaActualizada: Feriados): Promise<Number>{
  const tablaAGuardar = await this.repository.merge(tablaActualizada);
  return await this.guardar(tablaAGuardar)
}

async guardar(tabla:Feriados){ 
  await this.repository.save(tabla)
  return tabla.id 
}
```

I fixed it by removing the 2 @Transactional()
I hope someone helps.

Answer (score 0):

In `typeorm v0.3` the `Connection` API was replaced by the `DataSource` API. NestJS adapted this change as well, so if you relied on the old API (e.g. `getConnection` method) you might see the `Connection "default" was not found` error.

You can read about the changes and the new API in the release notes: https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/releases/tag/0.3.0

If you used `getConnection` you can use `app.get(DataSource)` instead.

Comment: how can I use `app.get(DataSource)` in my service class?

Answer (score 0):

In the new version of Typeorm, 0.3.7, a solution to this problem is next:

1. In the app.module.ts, change the constructor of the AppModule class and create a method to return Datasource:

   ```
   export class AppModule {
       constructor(private dataSource: DataSource) {}

       getDataSource() {
          return this.dataSource;
       }
   }
   ```
2. Then, in the file you need to use add:

   ```
   const repository = app
       .get(AppModule)
       .getDataSource()
       .getRepository('Entity_name');
   ```